# What's the best C# Twitter API for a twitter bot

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm writing a C# app that will be required to integrate with twitter, I need to be able to do the following:

- send direct messages
- read all messages that are either @helloapp or #helloapp

If you are interested the app is part of [Carsonified](http://carsonified.com)'s app in 4 days for FOWA. Read more [here](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/sketches-wireframes-logo-ideas-meet-our-new-app/) or see the [tweets](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23helloapp).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm gonna try TweetSharp, I'll let you know how I get on...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) can take care of both those requirements.

Yedda doesn't support Direct Messages as of now.

Comment: I'm having some trouble sending a direct message, I have: FluentTwitter.CreateRequest().AuthenticateAs(USR, PWD).DirectMessages().Send(RECIPIENT_USR_ID, "Thanks!").Request(); But this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I found a workaround: twitterRequest.Statuses().Update("d " + tweet.User.Name + " Thanks").Request();

Comment: Yikes, that first example should work (and default to XML). Can you file a bug?

Comment: TweetSharp  is dead, Yedda is dead

Answer (score 9):

See available APIs [here](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet)

I think most preferable will be [Yedda Twitter Library](http://devblog.yedda.com/index.php/twitter-c-library/)

Answer (score 7):

I prefer using [Twitterizer](http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/).

Comment: UPDATE: I have moved to TweetSharp because it has a steeper learning curve, but more features.  If you only need very basic stuff, use Twitterizer, if you need more advance stuff such as caching and OAuth, look at Tweetsharp.

Comment: Here is the link : [https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better option if you are after a **light-weight solution**.

I wrote a Twitter Bot in C# for [@valuetraderteam](https://twitter.com/ValueTraderTeam), it runs a heartbeat on a schedule and performs GET/POST actions to send [website related tweets](http://valuetrader.net) and add/remove friends from my list.

The API component in the GIST below is less than 500 lines, should be easy enough to add it to any project, only dependency is [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) which you might already have installed.

https://gist.github.com/sdesalas/c82b92200816ecc83af1

Hopefully this is useful to some other people out there.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post got marked as answered but I wanted to share how easy it is to send messages to multiple users at once with Tweetinvi (http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/).

```
IToken token = new Token("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
ITokenUser u = new TokenUser(token);
// Publish Direct Message to all the followers
u.PublishMessage("Hello world!", u.followers);
// Done!
```

I believe this can be of great help to develop a twitter bot.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/).  This is a 3rd party LINQ provider that I created that allows developers to interact with the Twitter API.  If you're writing a C# application to interact with Twitter, this is another option in addition to the other libraries mentioned in other posts.

Comment: Care to expand on / summarize what's beyond that link?  Link-only answers are frowned upon 'round these parts.

Comment: jadarnel27 - Fair enough - more explanation added. I found this post, which mentioned other C# Twitter libraries and think the answer space would be more complete for historical purposes if I added my own library.

Comment: Great, thanks Joe.  It's always good (when posting links to your own software / libraries on here) to both disclose your affiliation *and* make it relevant to the particular question (which you've done quite well now).  Lest ye be seen as a spammer.

Comment: we need access without API keys. Twitter has lost it went full anti- whatever and is banning accounts right and left