# How to write a command line C# program that posts to Twitter

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

I'd like to write a console program in C# that posts a Tweet to Twitter.  I've never used the Twitter APIs before and don't know anything about how their authentication works.  I found an API library called Twitterizer, but it seems geared towards web applications and wants the user to logon with a web browser.  All the API docs on Twitter's website seems geared around this scenario as well.

Is it possible to access the Twitter APIs using a console app with no web browser access?  I'm perfectly fine hard coding in the name and password for the Twitter user I want to post under as well.  Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259269/whats-the-best-c-twitter-api-for-a-twitter-bot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use OAuth for authenticating in twitter.

Then use regular HTTP Request to use the twitter JSON-based API.

[Here you can find](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/twitter-development-using-oauth-authenticate-against-twitter-api-walkthroughs) a good article about OAuth, Twitter and console applications.

Comment: So, does this mean the console app will popup a web browser for the user to logon?  I can't have this either.

Comment: @Mike No, that's not what it means.

Comment: The article has this code: var authorizationUrl = String.Format(AuthorizeUrl, collection[0]); Process.Start(authorizationUrl); which of course will spawn a web browser..

Comment: For OAuth to work, the user needs to allow the application to access their data and this is done in a web browser. When the user allows access they are presented with a PIN which is entered back into the application.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a loot at [linq2twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com) lib. From it's documentation;

> The Twitter API is built using
>   Representable State Transfer (REST).
>   Wikipaedia defines REST as "...a style
>   of software architecture for
>   distributed hypermedia systems...",
>   but I'm going to be so bold as to try
>   to simplify what that means. In
>   practice, REST is a Web service
>   protocol built upon Hypertext Transfer
>   Protocol (HTTP). You use the REST Web
>   service by making an HTTP call with a
>   URL and getting text back in some
>   form, which is often XML or JSON. So,
>   if you were to write code that made an
>   HTTP request with the following URL:
>
> http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.xml
>
> You would get back an XML document
>   with all of the Twitter statuses from
>   the public timeline, which is a
>   snapshot in time of the last 20 tweets
>   at the time of your request. Go ahead
>   and open your browser, copy and paste
>   the URL above into the address bar,
>   and see what you get back.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any decent information on the web on how to do this, so I decided to write my own blog post with all the details..  Enjoy!

http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2011/01/22/rise-of-the-twitterbot/

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use anything to connect to Twitter via RESTful api.
you should use oauth, and set up your application in http://dev.twitter.com, then you should read all articles listed in documents, you must specify your app as Client but not Browser so user input a number to get through authentication.
you can use many libraries so that you can save your time, all are listed in the documents
and be CAREFUL, you should not use Twitter's own api console which is buggy (as i know parameters somtimes can't be parsed), you should use APIgee instead which is powerful and stable.
if you want use basic authentication, you should use api proxy (one famous is twip), if you just need only one single C# apps, you must code by yourself:

1. you should use given username and password to login twitter, parse cookies passed
2. use normal oauth to get temporaly access token url.
3. use cookies got from step 1, emulates form submit to allow your apps, capture PIN code
4. use pin code to finish oauth.
5. MOST IMPORTANT, you must store access token in client's machine so next time you can bypass above steps

Comment: The main question I'm trying to find an answer for is can I use OAuth if I want to hard code in the user name and password rather than having an arbitrary user logon with a web browser.

Comment: in fact you can't access directly to twitter api with username and password, oauth doesnot allow this. you can use twitter api proxy to archive your goal. one famous i know is twip (hosted in google code) you can use Client App so you wont need to give a callback url.

Comment: It looks like twip is written in PHP, and I'm using C# code so that's a no go..  I don't understand, it's all just HTTP so I should be able to do whatever I want.

Comment: you must implement by yourself (i have edited answer) or you can use it by using a php server and replacing baseurl to it

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is against TWitter's policy so not gonna go down that route.  I'm gonna give TweetSharp a try and see if it works any better for console apps.

Comment: Looks like TweetSharp has an AuthenticateAs() method that takes a username and password, but Twitter returns the error "Basic authentication is not supported." for any request.  I guess Twitter used to support this, but no longer allows it?  Oh well, I guess there's no easy way to do when I'm trying to do.

Comment: now twitter only accept oauth but not basic. so you must use my way in the answer to emulate basic authentication

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a Twitter Bot in C#. This is currently posting tweets to [@valuetraderteam](https://twitter.com/valuetraderteam).

https://gist.github.com/sdesalas/c82b92200816ecc83af1

The API component in the GIST below is less than 500 lines, only dependency is [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), you'll need to download the latest DLL for either x64 or x86 (depending on what platform you are targetting) and include as a reference in your project.

There is an example at the bottom of the page of how you can make a tweet from a console application

Hopefully this is useful to some other people out there.