# What's a Good Twitter SDK for C#?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

Can anyone recommend a good Twitter SDK for C# (preferably open source)?

I found several on places like codeplex such as NTwitter. But these are a few years old and Twitter recently changed the login to OAuth.

I'll be using it from a WinForms app, although I may want to integrate with WPF at some point in the future.

**NOTE:** All I really need to do is post tweets programmatically. So if anyone has something simpler that allows this and supports OAuth, I'd be very interested in that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best C# Twitter API for a twitter bot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259269/whats-the-best-c-twitter-api-for-a-twitter-bot)

Comment: @Kon: Twitter has undergone major changes recently in the way clients connect to the service. Just because this has been discussed at some point years ago does not mean there's no room to discuss it again.

Comment: Perhaps I just haven't seen any of these changes impacting the client APIs such as TweetSharp.  Still works the same for me.  What hasn't worked for you?

Comment: @Kon: Show me where I said TweetSharp has failed to be updated and no longer works. What I said was that, given that the requirements have changed, I think it's valid to discuss it again.

Comment: My point being that if all still functions the same, then requires haven't really changed.

Comment: @Kon: I don't know how else to explain this to you. **Not all still functions the same!** Some libraries may have been updated so they still work, others may not. That's why another discussion is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CodePlex is your friend :)

I have used TweetSharp before with good success. http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Dead link, it seems that the project is hosted on github now: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Comment: New updated link: [https://github.com/shugonta/tweetsharp](https://github.com/shugonta/tweetsharp)

Answer (score 1):

Try [linqtotwitter.codeplex.com](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com). It supports .Net 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

As I have written in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914003/how-to-use-twitter-api-v1-1-for-c-net/18357769#18357769), [Tweetinvi](http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/) is a C# Twitter API that allow you to very easily perform many operations on Twitter 1.1 REST and Stream API.

> All I really need to do is post tweets programmatically. So if anyone has something simpler that allows this and supports OAuth, I'd be very interested in that.

I am suggesting this library to you as it has 3 level of abstraction divided in 3 different projects and you can decide how you want to use the API.

From Tweetinvi project :

```
IToken token = new Token("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
Tweet t = new Tweet("Hello world");
t.Publish(token);
```

From TwitterToken :

```
IToken token = new Token("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
token.ExecutePOSTQuery("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=helloTwitter");
```

You can even use the OAuth project that will create the WebRequest for you and you'll just have to parse the response sent from Twitter.

```
OAuthToken t = new OAuthToken("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
t.ExecuteQuery("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello Twitter From OAuth", HttpMethod.POST, null);
```

Hope this help you decide.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/19570670/C-Lab-Write-a-Simple-Twitter-Client-Using-the-Twitter-API

Comment: Thanks. I took a quick look but this appears to use the old style way of connecting to Twitter and not OAuth. If so, this technique obsolete and will not work.