# How to use twitter api v1.1 for C#.NET?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, twitter

Could any body provide me steps of authenticated twitter api V1.1 (means provide me steps of code) for C#.NET.

Comment: What have you already tried, and what research have you done?

Comment: Check [this out](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp).

Comment: actually i was download a VB.net code form this link https://github.com/mnotaro/TwitterOAuthV1.1Test here mention the v1.1 but use the v1.0 so plz help me!

Comment: any final solution with full sample ?

Answer (score 4):

I followed tweetsharp API "https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp" for posting tweet which support API V1.1.

Use library package manager and run command "PM> Install-Package TweetSharp " on package manger console .

```
    var _consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"].ToString();
    var _consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"].ToString();
    var _accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccess"].ToString();
    var _accessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessSecret"].ToString();

    var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
    service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);
    var status = "Collaborative short story of the day: Blah";
    var response = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status = status });
```

Comment: Could not find the package TweetSharp. Is it still supported?

Answer (score 2):

I have personally never used the above solutions but I feel they are quite the same.
Here is how to do with Tweetinvi C# API ([website](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/)).

1st step is to create a Token for your Application on Twitter website. A Token will allow you to connect to Twitter and perform queries against the REST API 1.1.

With this ConsumerToken (application token) you can ask for a user of your application to create a Token by using the TokenCreator class.

```
TokenCreator tokenCreator = new TokenCreator("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
```

If you already have the UserToken information you can simply create a Token by providing the information you want.

```
IToken token = new Token("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
```

When you have your Token you can perfom any operation you want.

Create a TweetExample :

```
IToken token = new Token("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
Tweet t = new Tweet("Hello world");
t.Publish(token);
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Twitter library page: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries