# C#: How to login to Twitter in web browser?

Tags: c#, twitter

Can you guys help me login to Twitter with C#'s web browser?

I got the ID's of the form(s) and put it into my code to make it fill the forms, and login but nothing happened.

Can anyone help?

This is the code that should work to post to the username and password fields but nothing happens:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("session[username_or_email]").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("session[password]").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
```

This is the exact link or page I want to login too: https://twitter.com/#!/login/

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code and explain exactly where you are having difficulties?

Comment: I posted some sample code that should work above ^^^

Comment: @Oded Hey, the code is in the first post above, maybe you can help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using a C# Twitter API? Various alternatives are listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259269/).

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, and why it has to use a web component instead of communicating via an API?

Comment: I am trying to make it confirm my Twitter account. The easiest way to do it is to visit the confirmation link with the web browser. Thats why I need it to login through regular Twitter, no API or anything.

Comment: Why don't you visit the link in a regular browser? It's just a one-off process and is best done manually.